# Evaluate $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ \sin(1/h)}{(1/h)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I go about:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ \sin(1/h)}{(1/h)}$$

Simply equating it to $1$ would be wrong cause as $h$ tends to $0$, $\sin(1/h)$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Hint : $\sin {x}$ is a bounded function.

Comment: Take $h=.001$, to get an idea of what the answer seems to tend to. This gives us $\frac{\sin1000}{1000}=.001\sin1000$. Since $-1\le\sin\le1$, we have $-.001\le\frac{\sin1000}{1000}\le.001$, which means that it's pretty close to zero. That's not a proof, but it gives us the idea that the limit is probably zero.

Comment: Thanks for that @columbus8myhw Will remember to do that in future in calculus. :)
And can someone please explain what bounded function means? Probably by taking \sinx as an example

Comment: "Bounded" means it has a maximum and a minimum. For example, $\sin$ is bounded, because $-1\le\sin(x)\le1$ for all $x$. On the other hand, $x^2$ isn't bounded, because it has no maximum. (It _is_, however, "bounded below", which means there is a minimum.) P.S. I'm only talking about _global maxima/minima_; local maxima and minima don't count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-1\le\sin\dfrac 1 h \le 1.$$

Therefore

$$
-|h|\le h\sin\dfrac 1 h \le |h|.
$$

If you can show that $|h|\to0$ and $-|h|\to0$ then it's not hard to see what happens to the thing squeezed between them.

Comment: Why is the middle part of the inequality not $$\color{red}|h\color{red}|\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)$$?

Comment: @alexqwx : If $h$ is positive, then $-h\le h\le h$ and if $h$ is negative, then $h\le h\le -h$, but either way this says $-|h|\le h\le |h|$.  If $h$ is positive, then $-h\le h\sin\dfrac1h\le h$, and if $h$ is negative, then $h\le h\sin\dfrac1h\le -h$, but either way, we have $-|h|\le h\sin\dfrac1h\le |h|$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin\frac1h}{\frac1h}=h\sin\frac1h\xrightarrow[h\to 0]{}0$$

since $\;\sin\frac1h\;$ is bounded.